# Terraform: How to implement a conditional step of moving forward, with timeout?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In a terraform stack, I am wishing to wait until an EC2 instance's dns name becomes available so that I can create CNAME records pointing to it, rather than A records pointing to the IP address. The goal is to make these record's accuracy persist machine restarts, which is not the case when using an IP address without an EIP.

I attempted the following `depends_on`, however terraform rejects this with
`References in depends_on must be to a whole object (resource, etc), not to an attribute of an object.`
See:

```
# Create EC2 instance
resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  ami                    = "..."
  instance_type          = "..."
  subnet_id              = "..."
  key_name               = "..."
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["..."]

  # User data script
  user_data = "${file("user_data.sh")}"
}

# Route53 A Record
resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_rec" {
  zone_id = "..."
  name    = "..."
  type    = "A"
  records = [aws_instance.server.public_dns]
  ttl     = 300

  depends_on = [aws_instance.server.public_dns]
}
```

What would be the correct approach here? I am using Terraform 1.5.
Assuming empty strings evaluate falsey, I was hoping to be able to poll the attribute for truthiness every *n* seconds, proceeding only once `true`. Is this possible?

Comment: So you observed that the record was being created before the DNS name was available?

Comment: @Paolo That's correct, but it fails for that reason. The record never gets created because AWS (as they should) refuses to accept an empty string for that parameter.

Comment: @MrChadMWood I'm wondering why would you need that? It sounds kind of like an anti-pattern, but I'm interested to hear more.

Comment: @MarkoE I just figured the `dns` link to the EC2 instance would persist restarting the instance, where a public IP (non EIP) does not. The IP changes when an instance is restarted. The idea is -- if the record uses a CNAME to point to the EC2s `dns` link instead, then restarting my EC2 instance would not mean I also must update the DNS records. Maybe there's a better way though?

Comment: But even if you manage to do it (I'm not sure if that is possible), when the instance does restart, the DNS name will be changed as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MarkoE Maybe that's where I'm going wrong... Now I'm trying to confirm if that's right, but I can't seem to find the info. Some docs indicate that the "resource based hostname" uses the instance_id for its convention. I imagine an instance_id would be the same after a reboot -- and I guess I am assuming that would carry over to the "resource based hostname" as well. I guess I should do some testing... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-naming.html

Comment: I was wrong. Seems the public DNS is not stable between stoping and starting an instance -- same as an IP address. https://serverfault.com/questions/329585/ec2-is-an-instances-public-dns-stable-can-i-rely-on-it-not-changing

Comment: In case it helps, a more typical way to expose a service at a stable hostname is to use an "elastic load balancer" (elb) or "application load balancer" (alb) alongside one or more EC2 instances, and then use the load balancer's hostname as the "stable" hostname. You can then, over time, replace the EC2 instances behind the load balancer -- with each one getting a new IP address -- without changing the load balancer's own hostname.